# Python Library Path

Tags: python

In ruby the library path is provided in `$:`, in perl it's in `@INC` - how do you get the list of paths that Python searches for modules when you do an import?

Comment: In Ruby I think you meant `$:`. `$"` is a list of modules loaded by `require`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer and others to this related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38485710/436794

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I think you're looking for [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

```
import sys
print (sys.path)
```

Answer (score 119):

You can also make additions to this path with the PYTHONPATH environment variable at runtime, in addition to:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/python-libs')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import sys
sys.path
```

Answer (score 6):

```
python -c "import sys; print('\n'.join(sys.path))"


/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```