# I have uploaded a Python package in pip, then pip installed this package, but I can't import this package in Python Interpreter

Tags: python, pip, pypi, pythoninterpreter

I have just uploaded a Python package into pip called hqc:

https://pypi.org/project/hqc/0.0.1/

then successfully pip installed the package using:

```
pip install hqc
```

[image: pip install hqc]
but I can't seem to import the package in Python Interpreter. When I do this, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import hqc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import hqc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'hqc'
```

What am I missing? Do I need to set the environment variable PATH or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder where setup.py is, make a folder called hqc and put an empty file called __init__.py (thats two underscores on each side). Right now, there's no file to import so python fails when importing it.

hqc-0.0.1:

[image]

hqc:

[image]

You can test the package by going to the directory where setup.py is and running

```
pip install .
```

Before trying again, be sure to uninstall

```
pip uninstall hqc
```

Comment: Should I be putting the source code for my package into the file called `__init__.py`? I currently have my source code in a file called `HQC.py` which sits in the same folder where `setup.py` is.

Comment: You can either do that or you can move HQC.py to the hqc folder and import everything like this: from hqc.hqc import *

Comment: Ok I have put my source code into `__init__.py`, created a hqc folder where `setup.py` is and put the `__init__.py` file into this hqc folder, and it worked! Many thanks for this! The guide (https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) clearly doesn't say `__init__.py` needs to be in a folder, where this folder is in the same directory as `setup.py`

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look at your github repository and found that the package name, i.e. your folder name is `skltemplate`.

So, your import will be: (verified it to be working)

```
import skltemplate
```

And found that `skltemplate` package exposes the following modeules:
TemplateClassifier, TemplateTransformer and TemplateEstimator.

You can import the above by doing:

```
from skltemplate import TemplateClassifier
```

- Now, if you want your package to be named as `hqc`, you need to rename `skltemplate` directory to `hqc` AND run the `setup.py` again. (You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13254104/6400614) stackoverflow answer for more details).
- Ensure that you increment the package version inside setup.py before running it.

Comment: That's strange because my github repository should be: https://github.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier. If you click on "Homepage" on the left hand side of this page, https://pypi.org/project/hqc/0.0.1/, it brings you to https://github.com/leockl/helstrom-quantum-centroid-classifier

Comment: Yes, that's repo I ended up at. Here is an image of that: https://ibb.co/7tR9DWH

Comment: My github is a little messy at the moment, so probably that's why you got the repositories confused, apologies about this