# Django Import Module Error

Tags: python, django

I'm very first on Django and I have a project from other friend and when I'm going to do manage python runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 457, in execute_manager
    setup_environ(settings_mod)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 433, in setup_environ
    import_module(project_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named Django_Project
```

My python version is Python 2.7.3

Please maybe someone could help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add you project,Django  to python path and then run this command.

To add to python path refer the following link [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Answer (score 0):

[As per the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), you have to change into the outer Django_Project directory when you execute the runserver command.

Comment: I'm really newbie (sorry) but how can I do this?

Comment: 'pwd' will tell you which directory you're currently in. You need to change into the Django_Project directory by typing 'cd <FULLPATH>' which at a guess is going to be something like '/Users/<YOURUSERNAME>/' then wherever you created the Django_Project project.

Comment: I mean I executed into the directory /Django_Project, what do you mean?

Comment: Can you show the command prompt from which you ran the command please?

Comment: /home/alu3875/dsi/Django_Project