# How to import a single function to my main.py in Python from another module?

Tags: python, import

In my script I have a function inside a module which I wish to be able to use in my main module to prevent redundancy. This other module (not my main, let's call it `two.py`) contains several classes and to import a class for use in another module one would use

```
from someDirectory.two import ClassA
```

Which works fine for importing the entire class, but say I have a function `myFunction()` in a different class `ClassB` contained in the same `two.py` module, which I want to be able to use in my `main.py`.

Is there a way which I can "grab" that function for use in my `main.py` or other modules, without having to import the entire class or redefine the same function?

Comment: Why do you need this? can you explain so that we can provide an optimal answer?

Comment: Perhaps the function does not belong in the class.  It sounds like a helper function that does not refer to the object's state.

Comment: Yes sure, I have a function which converts numbers to a specific formatted string and did not wish to define the same exact function for each module.  While I could do that it seems to me to be quite redundant and obviously not the most elegant solution

Comment: @user2497792:  I think you misunderstand.  I'm not suggesting that you re-implement the function for each module.  I'm suggesting that you implement it once and import it as needed.  There is nothing inelegant about using functions.

Comment: That is indeed the solution I am looking to accomplish, and I would hope not functions are a staple to quite a bit of programming, I am just new to python and still learning of it's features/syntax

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that the directory you wish to import code from is in your system path e.g.:

```
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_your_module_dir)
```

Then you can go ahead and do

```
from module import function
```

**UPDATE**

The following thread has details of how to permanently add the directory to your pythonpath in either Windows or Unix-like systems:

[Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Comment: I will look into that method, that would make sense as to why I am receiving an error

Comment: @user2497792 what os are you working on? I know this works for Windows as I often use it, but not sure for others.

Comment: I am using linux, centos5 to be specific

Comment: @user2497792 I have updated the above with a link to a thread that may be helpful.

Comment: I saw that I am actually checking it out now, thanks

Comment: –1 do not modify `sys.path` directly.