# Import static method of a class without importing the whole class

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to import some function in a class without needing to import the whole class.

I have some class as follows

---

### MyClassFile.py

```
class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            pass #Some init stuff

        def some_funcs(self):
            pass #Some other  funcs

        @staticmethod
        def desired_func():
            pass #The func i want to import
```

---

### MyScript.py

```
from MyClassFile import MyClass.desired_func
```

or

```
from MyClassFile.MyClass import desired_func
```

I tried to import that way but isn't work, is there any way to do it?

Comment: Hi Ivan, what's your reason for not wanting to import the class?

Comment: There is no way to do it in one import statement. When would that be useful? If it's a static method, make it a standalone function.

Comment: @Miket25 That doesn't seem to be asking the same question. This is asking about using import to access attributes of a class, which is not a factor in the question you linked.

Comment: @DavidZ The question asks how do you import some function of a class and have its use available in another file. The question I linked with the accepted answer points to that it's not possible to link attributes of a class, being the methods. Can you please explain what's different; I'm not sure if I get your difference?

Comment: @Ajax123 why did you reopen this question?

Comment: It is useful because the function i want to import is a parser used in another script, if i had put the function outside the class it wont be categorized well because there are multiple classes with multiple parsers (i wont name the function "parser_for_class_A" and so on, instead ClassA.parser) and i dont want to import the whole class because i think is not Pythonic to import stuff that i wont use it

Comment: @vaultah while the question can be reclosed, the answer provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346950/how-to-import-a-single-function-to-my-main-py-in-python-from-another-module requires the use of `sys`, thus requiring an additional import, which the OP seems to want to avoid.

Comment: @Ajax1234 there's no indication that Ivan wants to avoid importing the `sys` module. On second thought, that was a poor duplicate target, so no harm was done, I guess

Comment: Import sys to import a function? Thats sound awful isnt' it?

Comment: @IvanGonzalez you **always** import the whole module. You can't import just part of a module. The whole module is executed. If you do something like `from my_module import my_function` you can still check `sys.modules` and find `my_module` even if `my_module` isn't in the global namespace.

Comment: Furthermore the answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346950/how-to-import-a-single-function-to-my-main-py-in-python-from-another-module) are both garbage.  New dupe is better, though.

Comment: @vaultah the duplicate mentioned now is much more specific to the question. Thank you for finding it.

Comment: @Miket25 I suppose it doesn't matter now, but if you'd still like me to explain, I'd be happy to do so in a chat room.

Comment: Ivan, the etiquette here is _not_ to edit the answer into your question, so I've rolled back your edit accordingly. If you want to mark a particular answer as having solved your problem, all you should do is accept it (and probably upvote it too), which you've already done. So you're all set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To play devil's advocate:

```
# MyScript.py
desired_func = __import__('MyClassFile').MyClass.desired_func
```

On a more serious note, it sounds like your `staticmethod` should actually just be a module level function.  [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html).

If you insist on having a staticmethod, pick one of the options below:

1. Import the class as usual and then bind a local function: `f = MyClass.desired_func`
2. In `MyClassFile.py`, after the class definition block, alias a module-level function to the staticmethod and then import that name directly.

Comment: Awesome, this works. I will search more about module level function, thank you

Comment: @IvanGonzalez  While it works, this backdoor use of `__import__` should be discouraged.

Comment: @IvanGonzalez don't do this... wim was being funny