# How to check that the anaconda package was properly installed

Tags: python, macos, numpy, installation, anaconda

I'm completely new to Python and want to use it for data analysis. I just installed Python 2.7 on my mac running OSX 10.8. I need the NumPy, SciPy, matplotlib and csv packages. I read that I could simply install the Anaconda package and get all in one. So I went ahead and downloaded/installed Anaconda 1.7.

However, when I type in:
    import numpy as np

I get an error telling me that there is no such module. I assume this has to do with the location of the installation, but I can't figure out how to:
A. Check that everything is actually installed properly
B. Check the location of the installation.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is this directory you have installed `Anaconda` to on your `PATHONPATH`?

Comment: adding to @Oleg9 comment, you also have to add `Anaconda/Scripts` to your `PATH`...

Comment: My pythonpath is "~/usr/bin/python", my anaconda path is "~/User/myname/anaconda". So no they're not the same. I'm trying to figure out how to change the path.

Comment: @user2454855 look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: It's better to add `~/anaconda/bin` to your `$PATH` than to mess with your `$PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can determine which version of python you are running when you get the error by looking at the results of `which python` from the commandline. It is likely that you are running the system version (although recent versions Mac OS X include numpy in its system python), rather than Anaconda's python distribution. If this is the case, you need to modify your `PATH` as suggested by Anaconda at the end of the install process. Assuming it was installed in `~/anaconda`, you would need to add something like:

```
export PATH=$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH
```

to your `.bash_profile`

Comment: Could you walk me through the steps? anaconda is installed in ~/User/myname/anaconda. So does that mean that in the bash command line I have to enter > $ echo "export PATH=User/myname/anaconda/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile

Comment: Note that the Anaconda installer usually does this for you, unless you explicitly tell it not to. At any rate, enter the line exactly as it's written here (with `$HOME`). That will be better than writing out the full path to your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Though the question is not relevant to Windows environment, FYI for windows. In order to use anaconda modules outside spyder or in cmd prompt, try to update the PYTHONPATH & PATH with C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages.

Finally, restart the command prompt.

Additionally, sublime has a plugin 'anaconda' which can be used for sublime to work with anaconda modules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the existing answer answers your specific question (about installing packages within Anaconda). When I install a new package via `conda install <PACKAGE>`, I then run `conda list` to ensure the package is now within my list of Anaconda packages.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try this:

for anaconda 2 :

```
export PATH=~/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

for anaconda 3 :

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

for anaconda 4 :

Use the Anaconda Prompt

and then

```
conda --version
```

to confirm that it worked.