# What's the correct way to import a python package?

Tags: python, testing, module, path, operating-system

I have a python project structured as of now in the following way:

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   bar/
       __init__.py
       config.cfg
       README.md
       src/
          __init__.py
          myfile_a.py
          myfile_b.py
       tests/
          test_myfile_a.py
   README.md
```

and inside `test_myfile_a.py` I have:

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 import unittest
  3 from foo.bar.src import myfile_a
  4 
  5 class TestToolsFunctions(unittest.TestCase):
  6 
  7     def setUp(self):
  8         file_a = MyFile_A()

  9   if __name__ == '__main__':
  10     unittest.main()
```

then i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/test_myfile_a.py", line 3, in <module>
    from foo.bar.src import myfile_a
ImportError: No module named foo.bar.src
```

What is the correct way to set that path?

** EDIT **
The `foo` directory is a git repo, on my `~/home` dir: `/home/pribeiro/foo`
I also tried to do a `import foo`:

```
import foo
ImportError: No module named foo
```

Comment: Where is `foo` located? Does `import foo` work?

Comment: I see at least 3 questions in the 'Related' list on the RHS of the page that are likely to provide you with the answer to your question.

Comment: If `import foo` doesn't work you will probably have to `import sys` and then `sys.path.append(<Directory>)` to add it to your PATH.

Comment: @chepner question was updated ...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler no, they could not help me ... I had done the search before ...

Comment: @grandocu let me trying `import foo`

Comment: @grandocu `import foo` did not work :-(

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=$HOME python yourscript`?

Answer (score 0):

Is foo in your PATH? 
Try

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If you add foo to your path, foo.bar.src should be a valid module

Comment: How to add `foo` to the path?

Comment: @grandocu's comment (using sys.path.append) will work, but only for that session (command/terminal window). To add it permanently depends on your platform (linux/mac?). It is simple on windows, bit more involved on linux. I'll look, there are several SO posts about it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath should help

Comment: does `print sys.path` return the directory you added?

Comment: it does ... @grandocu