# Eclipse Pydev import issues and pythonpath

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pythonpath

I'm unable to run my code in Eclipse `pyDev`. I get these red stars on my 'src' project folder as you can see in this [screenshot](http://some.net63.net/index.html).

And here is the error output when I import the project:

```
ImportError: No module named framework.api_driver.driver
```

Any idea why? I've already set up my path variable to point to `C:\python27` and also added another PYTHON var to point to `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` even though the site-packages dir is empty.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: Where is `framework.api_driver.driver` installed if site-packages is empty?

Comment: You would have to add that folder to sys.path.

Comment: Thanks M4rtini, how do I do that; should I copy that folder to the PATH var under environment variables?

Comment: I also updated the screenshot to show you where I think the driver is; please help me out w/ this. I won't take much of your time, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"path to notematic_test")
```

The import should now work.

Comment: Sorry M4rtini, you can see that im still learning but do I add that line at the top of all of my .py test files?

Comment: Yeah that's what you would have to do. There are other way's do do it, but unless this is a permanent location for it. I usually just add the path like this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath This post give's many other alternatives.

Comment: weird, maybe the string got escaped. try to put a r in front of the string(`r"c:\user..."`). Both the framework and api_driver have a `__init__.py` file in them, so they should get recognized as module folders.