# Python does not import module that it's path is in sys.path

Tags: python, django, import

Ok i have a file in

```
C:\Python27\pysec-master\pysec
```

and the `sys.path` is

```
>>> print sys.path
['C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec', 'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\idlelib',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib',
 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']
```

whenever i try to type

```
from pysec.models import *
```

it gives me a traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 1, in <module>
    from pysec import *
ImportError: No module named pysec
```

How is this possible since `pysec` is a physical file in the `Python` file and `C:\Python27\pysec-master\pysec` is in `sys.path`?

Inside the `pysec` file there is a `models.py` also.

EDIT

wait, inside the pysec file there is a models.py also.? HOW?

Please see the pic. If you have the picture capacity dissabled please tell me so.
[image]

Comment: wait, `inside the pysec file there is a models.py also.`? HOW?

Comment: I posted a picture to see

Comment: From your picture it is **clear** that Alex answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in your system-path instead of (looking at the picture in your edit, this is definitely the problem):

```
'C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec'
```

use:

```
'C:\\Python27\\pysec-master'
```

I think `pysec` is the module itself, not the directory in which the module resides.

Comment: Try it how? I type `from pysec.models import *` in the GUI and i get the error. I thought it may not have the path in `sys` and so i typed `sys.path` in the GUI and i got that the directory that leads to the pysec file exists in `sys.path` How to try that one up? where? just a little clue..

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant What Alex is saying is that you may have the *wrong* path in `sys.path`. How to check: does the file: `C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec\\pysec\\__init__.py` exist? (NOTE: there are *two* directories called `pysec` in that path). If yes, then something strange is happening. However you probably have a `C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec\\__init__.py` (NOTE: only *one* `pysec` directory in there). To check this: add a `sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\pysec-master")` *before* the import of `pysec.models`.

Comment: There is a `C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec' path but NOT a `C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec\\__init__.py` or a `C:\\Python27\\pysec-master\\pysec\\pysec\\__init__py` this would actually require the existence of a file called pysec inside of the one pysec file that exists, wouldn't it?                          NOTE that when i type in `sys.path.append("C:\\Python27\\pysec-master")` it does not throw an error with the command `from pysec import *`

Comment: I'm not surprised. You only really add directories for the system-path. As for appending to it, that doesn't surprise me, as the `pysec` module is in that directory. For the long term solution the path given in my answer needs to be added to your systempath.

Comment: Guys so is it because GUI sees pysec as a module we must think as Alex said: `I think pysec is the module itself, not the directory in which the module resides.` Please tell me i am so curious

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant Yes, the system-path is for directories with modules in them. When it sees the `pysec` it assumes it is a directory which is wrong. Look up some tutorials on adding to your system-path to make it work.

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant If my answer was helpful to you, would you mind accepting it by clicking on the tick below the vote counts so it turns green? Thank you.

Comment: Of course Alex i was just editing in order to make the thread easy to use!

Comment: I understand now why @Bakuriu told me about the two pysec\\pysec on his first comment!

Comment: Hey guys do you know how can i permanently add that path and not have to retype it every time i re-open the Python GUI?

Comment: @ExoticBirdsMerchant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see. `pysec` is a folder. So you should use

```
from model import *
```

If you intend to add something to your `sys.path` permantly, add this path to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.(Control Panel / System / Advanced / Environment variable), in the "User variables" sections, check if you already have `PYTHONPATH`. If yes, select it and click "Edit", if not, click "New" to add it.

Paths in `PYTHONPATH` should be separated with `;`.