# add a permanent directory to PYTHONPATH bug

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have tried to [add a permanent directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) from here but i didn't understand how to do it.
The answer states that:

*You need to add your new directory to the environment variable PYTHONPATH, separated by a colon from previous contents thereof.*

However I pressed the `Windows_Start Button` and the `Pause/Break Button` and in `Advanced System Settings` I went to `Environment Variables`

AND HERE'S THE PROBLEM

There is no Variable named `PYTHONPATH` to set-up a value there!!! It must be a bug!

These are the values that exist in my `System variables`

```
ComSpec
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS
OS
Path
PATHEXT
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER
PROCESSOR_LEVER
PROCESSOR_REVISION
PSModulePath
TEMP
TMP
USERNAME
windir
windows_tracing_flags
windows_tracing_logfile
```

See my problem is that i use `sys.path.append()` to add the directory but once i restart the `GUI` i must re-input the command.

The [solution aforementioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) and linked states that i must find the `PYTHONPATH` and add the directory there but i have no `Environment Variable` named `PYTHONPATH`

How can i run around this problem?

**EDIT**

Create a file start-my-app.cmd using a text editor (Notepad is good, Word/Wordpad is bad). Copy the code above and replace the parts between ... with what you need. Double click start-my-app.cmd or type start-my-app.cmd in a command prompt (you need to be in the same folder as start-my-app.cmd for this to work). –  Aaron Digulla

-->Like this

[image]

**THIS IS HOW I DID IT. IS IT CORRECT? PLZ TELL ME**

1. Go to Environment Variables
2. Click the `New` Button in System Variables
3. Fill in the variable details

It looks suspiciously easy to me in contrast to the answers i have received but it works and every time i open the GUI i dont have to `append` the path. If there is anything wrong with this solution plz tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new one; the comment above only means: "If there already is one, don't just overwrote the current value".

That said, I don't like changing global environment variables much. First of all, you must not forget to restart all command prompts because existing ones don't get new variables.

My preferred solution is to create a `.cmd`/`.bat` file which contains:

```
set PYTHONPATH=...whatever your code needs...

python ...and start your Python code here...
```

That way the variable will be there when you expect it, no matter when and from where you start the script and it will not interfere with other stuff that you might also have.

Comment: Well i type these commands (set PYTHONPATH...) in the `cmd`? And what is a .cmd/bat file? Can you expand a little bit your ansewer plz?

Comment: Create a file `start-my-app.cmd` using a text editor (Notepad is good, Word/Wordpad is bad). Copy the code above and replace the parts between `...` with what you need. Double click `start-my-app.cmd` or type `start-my-app.cmd` in a command prompt (you need to be in the same folder as `start-my-app.cmd` for this to work).

Comment: Will it set it permanently? If i put the file in `C:\Python27\pysec-master` where the work is being done? Will i have to type `start-my-app.cmd` in the `cmd` in every time i start to work?

Comment: No, the variable exists only as long as the batch script is running. You now have to use this batch script to start the software instead of the original command.

Comment: Dear Aaron (thank you for your patience most of all!) i am confused on `the variable exists only as long as the batch script is running` --> doesn't that mean that in order the variable to exist i must always initialize this file from the cmd? Is there a way to add this directory without and be available without having to initialize any file? Thanks in advance and sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Read this, it should answer at least half of your questions: http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them