# ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, importerror

I am a newbie.

Problem statement :

In directory sfdc_bulk i have 2 file 
1)helper.py
2)sfdclogin.py

helper.py

```
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM


def getElemVal(xmlString,elemName):
    #tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
    #print tree
    dom = DOM.parseString(xmlString)
    val=dom.getElementsByTagName(elemName)
    ret=None
    if len(val) >0 :
        ret=val[0].toxml()
        #.replace('<' + ret + '>', '').replace('</' + ret + '>', '')
        ret=ret.replace('<' +elemName+ '>','').replace('</' + elemName + '>', '')
    return ret
```

sfdclogin.py

```
from helper import getElemVal

print getElemVal('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>bar</foo>', 'foo')
```

inside the directory sfdc_bulk
using ubuntu terminal:

python sfdclogin.py

it returns bar

but after modifying the sfdclogin file to

```
from sfdc_bulk.helper import getElemVal

print getElemVal('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>bar</foo>', 'foo')
```

i am getting the follwing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sfdclogin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sfdc_bulk.helper import getElemVal
ImportError: No module named sfdc_bulk.helper
```

Comment: Is your `sfdc_bulk` directory on the Python path?  Does it have an `__init__.py`?

Comment: yes it have an empty __init__.py .

Comment: It should be `__init__.py`, not `init.py`.

Comment: this is not only init it have __ in the both side. But i don't know some how it is removed from my comment. thanks for your reply.

Comment: @HaiVu: That's just what shows up when you type `__init__.py` without backticks, since double underscores are interpreted as Markdown for bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both files are in the same directory, import it directly. Your first try:

```
from helper import getElemVal
```

Is already correct. Why change it?

Unless you want to treat `sfdc_bulk` as a package. Include it in the `PYTHONPATH`. In Windows it would be like:

```
$ set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\your\directory\sfdc_bulk
```

For use in Ubuntu, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Comment: when both the file in the same directory then it is fine. but if i would like to import from other directory then what should i do??
and why this approach is not working??

Comment: if would like treat as a package ??

Comment: That means, you want to import it from other directories.

Comment: yes. but i don't want to set in the PYTHONPATH, better i would like to treat as a package so i can run the same thing in other machine as well.

Comment: Then include the folder to the directory of anything you're working on. There's a reason why modules need to be installed, not just copied.. They set their files and path. That's how you get a package.

Comment: If this answers your question, please accept it by ticking the accept button next to this answer! Thank you.