# Can not import module in Mrjob

Tags: python, mrjob

I've tried change wordcount example using mrjob. My structure project is:

```
├── input_text.txt
├── store_xml_dir
│   ├── xml_file.xml
│   └── xml_parse.py
└── wordcount.py
```

and content of wordcount.py is:

```
import os
import sys
cwdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(cwdir)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(cwdir, "store_xml_dir"))

import xml_parse
# print dir(xml_parse) <- it works here if i'd comment the rest code

from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        getxml = xml_parse.GetXML()
        print '>>>', getxml.get_strings()

        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

When i run, i've got error: `ImportError: No module named xml_parse`. Why python can not import `xml_parse` in this case?

Comment: You need to put `store_xml_dir` in other nodes and add it to `pythonpath`. mrjob does not export your code to other nodes.

Comment: @SAM I've appended to `pythonpath` by using `sys.path.append(os.path.join(cwdir, "store_xml_dir"))`

Comment: It seems mrjob does not execute that line of code on task trackers. Maybe you need to do it manually.

Comment: @SAM But when run in local. The code isn't works.

Comment: spread xml directory on all hosts, then [add it permanently to pythonpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Comment: @SAM i've tried export `pythonpath` by command: `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`/store_xml_dir` then it works. But i don't know why `sys.path.append` isn't work in this case?

Comment: I updated my answer. I was wrong about it and mrjob can handle what you was trying.

Answer (score 0):

mrjob <strike>does not</strike> exports your **none mapreduce** code for you, <strike>You need to export it yourself.</strike> but you need to explicitly tell it to do so in configs. (take a look at their [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/configs-all-runners.html))

You can run your code by adding these config parameters:

```
--python-archive=store_xml_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that importing the modules within the member function solves this issue for me.

```
def mapper(self, _, line):
    import xml_parse
    ...
```