# Environment variables updates when the system reboots in fedora linux

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, reboot, pythonpath

I updated my **PYTHONPATH** variable in **bash_profile**

But changes take place when I reboot the machine.

Why?? Is there any better solution to this??

Answer (score 0):

[Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solution is to use [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) and even better with [virtualenvwrapper](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win)

**virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper Quick Start:**

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
source $(which virtualenvwrapper.sh)

mkvirtualenv foo

workon foo
```

**Note:** For Python 3.x users; Python 3.x now comes with [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

However putting an environment variable in your `$HOME/.bash_profile` typically only gets executed/evaluated once per login session (*you don't really need to rebot as such*).

Typically in Bash this means:

```
bash -l  # enter a new login session
```

However if you want the environment variable everywhere without having to start a new "login session" you should put it in `$HOME/.bashrc`.

**Example:**

```
echo -e "export PYTHONPATH=\$HOME/lib/python\n" >> $HOME/.bashrc
```