# Cant upgrade matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pip

When I try to uprgrade I get this:

Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ============================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.4.3]
                python: yes [2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)  [GCC
                        4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
Requires numpy 1.6 or later to build.  (Found 1.4.1)
```

But I've already updated numpy to 1.9.2

EDIT:
The updated numpy is in  /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy
The old numpy is in  /usr/share/doc/numpy-1.4.1

pip show numpy gives me

---

Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: numpy
Version: 1.9.2
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: NumPy Developers
Author-email: numpy-discussion@scipy.org
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Requires: 
[root@acnlin19 rogers]#

Comment: What do you get when you run 'pip list | grep numpy' and 'pip show numpy'?

Comment: Have you tried putting it in a virtualenv?

Comment: @cameron-f I get 1.9.2

Comment: @luminous12 have you tried uninstalling and reinstall numpy? pip uninstall numpy

Comment: @cameron-f yes. There is an old version of numpy on this computer that it keeps picking up vs the one I installed with pip

Comment: @luminous12 when you do pip show numpy what directory location does it give you? You should be able to pip uninstall until all numpy folders are gone from that directory

Comment: @cameron-f it gives me the location of the updated numpy

Comment: @luminous12 Can you edit your question to show the paths and pip outputs?  I'm stumped.  You could try virtualenv or [anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) as a workaround.  I'll have to see what someone else comes up with

Comment: @luminous12 after you run 'pip uninstall numpy' and then run 'pip show numpy' does it display anything?  Also in /usr/lib/share/doc is there a version.py file?  I think /usr/lib/share/doc is just for documentation.  A module will need at least an __init__.py

Comment: @cameron-f It does not display anything after I uninstall numpy then do pip show numpy. There also does not appear to be a version.py file in the usr/lib/share/doc

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install -U numpy
pip install matplotlib
```

These two comadns should sort you. Run as root if you aren't using a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

It is still detecting your old **numpy** version. I think you need to add path to **numpy** in PYTHONPATH environment variable

Comment: unfortunately it ended up giving me the same result

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath