# ImportError: No module named button, no module indeed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, anaconda, conda

I am trying to run a simple calculator code in Tkinter, which I found on the web [linked here](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/277522/gui-scientific-calculator-homework/).
The code uses the import button functions, which gives an

> **ImportError:** No module named button

I understand that I may be missing a package called **button**. I tried searching but couldn't find anything for my win-64 system. I tried

```
> anaconda search -t conda button
```

and

```
> pip install 'packages'
```

all the available packages but doesn't seem to work.

Please, can anyone tell me what am I missing? Thank you.

Comment: What does *"doesn't seem to work"* actually mean? Did you `pip install buttons`? What precise output did you get as a result? There is no such package on PyPI, perhaps it refers to http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/ppics1/code/chapter12/button.py

Comment: @jonrsharpe by "_doesn't seem to work_" I mean I am getting the ImportError. And `pip install` returns no matching distribution.

Comment: Also, you might want to check [Importing Self Written Python Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32509046/importing-self-written-python-module)

Comment: @Lafexlos are you saying the button isn't any package but it is a function defined inside the code?

Comment: It is not on PyPI, so you can't `pip install` it. I suggest you take a look at http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/. You will have to download the relevant `.py` files and put them somewhere you can `import` from.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Zelle's website has only _graphics.py_ module that I have saved it in my working directory and is working fine.

Comment: No, there are others - see the link in my first comment, from the same site.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks buddy problem solved.

Comment: why does this have the `tkinter` tag? It seems completely unrelated to tkinter.