# Python Interpreter can't import files until exited and restarted

Tags: python, import, module, interpreter, restart

I have my python files all saved in one directory ('F:\code').

When I enter the Python interpreter from the Windows command prompt :

```
F:\python
>>>
```

I can import any .py files created when I entered the interpreter. But I can't import any files created after the interpreter already started. I have to exit the interpreter and then open it again to be able to import any new .py modules.

I have tried:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('F:/code')
>>> sys.path.append('F://code')
>>> sys.path.append('F:\')
>>> sys.path.append('F:\\')
```

but get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module-whatever'
```

I have tried artificially creating a .pyc file in the **pycache** folder in the sub of the directory but that doesn't work either.

I'm not sure why I have to exit and re-enter the interpreter because I would like to be able to write .py scripts on the fly eventually and load them in the interpreter to debug.

Comment: Possibly Windows file permission shenanigans, see if [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32509496/) works.  Really though, this is something that is hard to reproduce, as I cannot reproduce this issue under my Windows VM (or Linux)

Comment: @metatoaster - Thank you!!!!! This solution you pointed to worked! I can create the .py file, not need to create a .pyc file and use >>>imp then >>>my_file = imp.load_source('module_whatever','F:/code/module_whatever.py')