# How to run manage.py when django project in egg

Tags: python, django, egg

After installed my django project, I found some files here:

```
/opt/pkgs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myproject-2.3-py2.7.egg/dashboard/management/commands/myjob.py
/opt/pkgs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myproject-2.3-py2.7.egg/manage.py
```

When run `python manage.py myjob` or `sudo python manage.py validate`, error is

```
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It is ugly to run `sudo python /opt/pkgs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myproject-2.3-py2.7.egg/manage.py validate`

How to fix it? Any useful doc?

**UPDATE**

sys.path:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL']
```

I failed to add path "/opt/pkgs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myproject-2.3-py2.7.egg/manage.py" to sys.path **permanently**.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) might help.