# pip not working on windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I am using python 2.7.10 on a windows 10 computer

In power shell pip does not work in any directory.  In `python27\scripts .\pip` will work.  My path is correct, but there are two in system variables "**Path**" and "**PSModulePath**".  The "**PSModulePath**" has the `Python27\Scripts` in the proper place.

Any suggestions.

Comment: What is your question? If your PATH variable is correct, then pip should work.

Comment: @franklin. The question is why does it not work

Answer (score 0):

I know that you've checked already but, it's most likely the Environmental Variables.

You can fix this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Another reason for pip not working is the version of Python/Pip you're using.

You can update this [here](https://www.python.org/).