# How to use virtualenv system-site-packages on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

I have to work on an existing python (django) application that runs on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It seems that all the requirements (from requirements.txt) are installed in a virtual env (I hope I'm right on that). My problem is that I have installed some libraries using yum. My dependencies config for my beanstalk instance looks like this:

```
packages:
 yum:
  python27-devel: []
  git: []
  nginx: []
  pcre-devel: []
  freetype-devel: []
  libpng-devel: []
  postgresql93-devel: []
  graphviz-devel: []
  blas-devel: []
  atlas-devel: []
  lapack-devel: []
  gcc-c++: []
  python27-numpy: []
  python27-matplotlib: []
  python27-psycopg2: []
```

As you can see I explicitly install some python libraries like numpy, matplotlib and psycopg2 but since my application seems to run in a virtual env these libraries are not accessible for my app so it crashes when launching. I got this type of errors:

> Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)....7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 20, in  raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named psycopg2. container_command 01_migrate in .ebextensions/02-python.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

I've read that you can allow a virtual env to access the system libraries with the option system-site-packages but how to do so for a AWS elastic beanstalk instance?

EDIT: What I don't want to do is installing numpy, matplotlib and psycopg2 with pip since it compiles everything and that's very long. It is why I want to install these libraries with yum, to get a precompiled version. And I want these installations to be automatic, I don't want to ssh on the machine to install things manually. This is where my problem appears. :)

Thanks a lot for your time!

(Sorry for my english, it's not my native language)

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR:
Add the following command to a config file under `.ebextensions` folder:

```
commands:
  01_add_dist_files_to_site:
    command: "echo /usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages > /opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/dist.pth"
```

This should expose the libraries under `/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages` (where yum installs numpy and scipy for example...) to the interpreter used by EB's virtualenv.

---

Elastic Beanstalk is using `/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt` to install your requirements. 
You need to set the python virtualenv in a way that will make it exposed to your installed packages.

Examining the site libraries that are accessible to EB's venv I found:

```
(venv)[root@ip-XXXXXX app]# /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python2.7 -msite
sys.path = [
    '',
    '',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7',
]
```

So it is enough to add a `.pth` file which contains paths to your desired libraries, to one of the listed folders (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311321/5715272)). This can be done as mentioned at the beginning. Note that you need your `requirements.txt` to hold python packages with the exact versions of the ones installed using yum, in order to skip unnecessary installation steps.