# Adding custom dir to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, macos, bash, python-2.7, pythonpath

I've been trying to add a custom directory to `PYTHONPATH` following the advice on this post [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath). I'm using bash on a Mac, if that's relevant. This is what I did:

1. `open ~/.bash_profile`
2. `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/Zhengnan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages"` and save
3. `source ~/.bash_profile`

There were two problems:

1. When I ran `sys.path` inside a Python IDE, the intended dir still didn't show up.
2. When I fired up Python in Terminal and ran `sys.path` there, the dir did show up, but all the other directories didn't match what I got from the previous step.

Specifically, this is what I got from running `sys.path` inside the IDE. The intended dir couldn't be found.

> > > sys.path
> > >       ['',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python27.zip',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages.zip',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
> > >        '/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/IPython/extensions',
> > >        '/Users/Zhengnan/.ipython']

And this is what I got from running `sys.path` from Terminal. The intended dir is the third element in the list.

> > > sys.path
> > >       ['', '/Users/Zhengnan', '/Users/Zhengnan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']

I should mention that the reason I want to add this custom dir to `PYTHONPATH` is that every time I `pip install` a package, it gets installed in `/Users/Zhengnan/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages` and I don't want to `sys.path.append` every time I run a script. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot going on here.

Fundamentally, the Python you are using in your IDE is not the Python you are using in the terminal.  This is why `pip install` doesn't put things in the right place.

The easiest solution is just to modify your `$PATH` environment variable so that when you type `python` in the terminal, you get the same version that your IDE is using.  My guess is that your IDE's `python` is something like `/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/bin/python`, in which case you would get rid of your `PYTHONPATH` setting your `.bash_profile` and add:

```
export PATH="/Applications/Spyder-Py2.app/Contents/Resources/bin:$PATH"
```

Assuming that `pip` is available in the same place, you should now be able to `pip install` things without needing to muck about with `PYTHONPATH`.

The other problem here is that environment variables set in the shell, e.g., in your `.bash_profile`, have no impact on the environment visible to applications.  It is *possible* to set environment variables that will be visible to OS X applications (e.g., see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x)), but it's tricky and I wouldn't advise it.

An alternate solution, if it's available, is just to tell your IDE which `python` it should be using, and point it at whichever one is visible from the terminal.