# Installing Pandas in anaconda

Tags: python

I'm encountering these errors:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 17, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 35, in <module>
    import pandas.core.strings as strings
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you sure `pandas` is on `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: how do i put it on pythonpath? sorry noob here. thanks

Comment: You may find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3402176/5399734