# Running Python syntax in command line vs. Python shell

Tags: python, command-line, sys

I hope this question will make sense. I have a piece of code that should be run from the command line:

```
python download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv --output=downloaded.tsv
```

When I run this, it gives me an import error:

> ImportError: No module named twitter

To find out why, I opened the Python shell by typing `python`. Then I checked `sys.path`, and found that the directory containing the twitter module was not in sys.path. So, I appended that directory, and `twitter` can now be imported.

However, it seems that

```
download_tweets_api.py --dist=tweeti-a.dist.tsv --output=downloaded.tsv
```

cannot be run from the Python shell, maybe because of the specific command line syntax? (I'm not so sure here)

So, I have to exit Python to return back to the 'normal' command line. However, then I lose my sys.path.append, and the twitter directory is no longer in sys.path.

What should I do?

Comment: You should add permanently the twitter location to your path. There is a lot of ways of doing this, I suggest you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: Which OS are you using? Windows? Linux? OSX?

Comment: I'm using Windows:)

Comment: did you add directory to `sys.path` in your script ? Adding directory in Python Shell nothing change.

Comment: `"cannot be run from the Python shell"` - from Python Shell you can't run any file - you can only `import` file and run function from this file. You can run files only from command line - `python some_script.py`