# Python 3 - Modules and Packages Mess - Architecture

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, architecture

Some months ago y started working in a small project that over the time became big. It started with a few python files:

```
project
│   program_1.py
│   program_2.py
```

We continue adding more programs, so in order to avoid code repetition I started extracting common functions to separate files.

```
project
│   program_1.py
│   program_2.py
│   program_3.py
│   shared_module_1.py
│   shared_module_2.py
```

We keep adding some more programs and they had a considerable size so I put them inside their own folders just like this. Also to avoid dropping more files inside the project folder (This is just a reduced example, folder has 15+ files):

```
project
│   program_1.py
│   program_2.py
│   program_3.py
│   shared_module_1.py
│   shared_module_2.py
└───program_4
    │   program_4.py
    │   program_4_aux.py
```

In order for the program_4.py to use the shared modules I had to use the following statement:

```
sys.path.append('../')
```

I am unable to keep up like this. Code is getting messy and hard to maintain. I have no idea how to clean this mess.

PD: I try using `from .. import shared_module_1` but it tells me `parent module '' not loaded cannot perform relative import`

Thanks you very much for your time.

Comment: The project is a set of usefull automation tools for the company. Many are already in use. I would love a way of cleaning this mess without breaking all code.

Comment: While I think this is a good question, it is a bit broad at the moment. Perhaps you can narrow it down to what you think could be a good layout and why it does not work?

Comment: My idea was to have this big folder containing all this set of handy scripts and being able to reuse some logic between them. I want to know what are the best practices (following python principles) to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Go and have a look at the way [django](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django) is laid out.

Salient notes:

- the root of the repository *is not* the main importable python module (i.e. there is no **init**.py file at the top-level). That is in the subdirectory `./django`.
- there should be no scripts, i.e. standalone python files that you can run inside the module. The `manage_translations.py` script uses some django functionality via import, but it lives in `./scripts`. Also scripts should **never** use relative imports (because scripts are not in modules!)
- tests also do not live inside the main module.
- if you think you need to modify `sys.path` you are probably doing it wrong.
- functionality within the django package is split logically based on its functionality. E.g. there is a submodule `./django/db` for handling database related functionality. If this is done well then a generic submodule (if there are any) could easily be moved to a separate project entirely if that was helpful.

So a suggestion would be to move all your module code into a subdirectory separate from your program code, something like:

```
project
    module
        __init__.py
        module_1.py
        module_2
            __init__.py
            submodule_a.py
    scripts
        program1.py
```

Then you only need to ensure that `project` is in your PYTHONPATH, and you will be able to do e.g.

```
from module.module_1 import Module1Class
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is adding the directory where you have your programs to PYTHONPATH enviromental variable as in [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Another solution is to call the program from the directory where you shared modules are:

```
python program_4/program_4.py
```

You should have a look at **init**.py files too, despite not being a solution.

The third option would be to have the shared modules in the python library package.