# Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu [Failed]

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, boot, autostart

I wanted to run a python script at boot in Ubuntu. 
I tried referring to few existing solutions in stackoverflow but somehow I don't get it working.
Could anyone advise me on what piece of info I am missing!

---

## Reference 1

Run Python script at startup in Ubuntu answered by @RickyA

Put this in `/etc/init` (Use /etc/systemd in Ubuntu 15.x)

**mystartupscript.conf**

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
exec /path/to/script.py
```

By placing this conf file there you hook into ubuntu's upstart service that runs services on startup.

manual starting/ stopping is done with **sudo service mystartupscript start** and **sudo service mystartupscript stop**

### **Results for Reference 1**

In my case, the python script that I wanted to run on boot is located in `/home/aspma/Dropbox/Linux/c_lynda_program_backup_script.py`

When I tried to manually start the service from terminal window, i got an error message: *`start Job failed to start`*

[Screenshot of mystartupscipt.conf file that i added inside /etc/init and its failed attempt for manual starting the service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nl8FG.png)

---

## Reference 2

How To Start Python Script On Bootup answered by @Germar

You can add it to `/etc/rc.local`. This can be used to run scripts and programs on system boot which doesn't have their own scripts for runlevels. It will run as `root`

Run `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and add your line before exit 0

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

python /home/my-sickbeard-install/SickBeard.py 2>&1 >/dev/null &

exit 0
```

### **Results for Reference 2**

In my case, the python script that I wanted to run on boot is located in `/home/aspma/Dropbox/Linux/c_lynda_program_backup_script.py`

[Screeenshot of file that is edited in /etc/rc.local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU0Hp.png)

This doesn't work too

---

**Virtual Machine Details**

Ubuntu Version 14.04.5 LTS

Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the python script run automatically at the boot, by adding one more step to the solution given in Reference 2 (see the  question).

By adding the directory of the python script to PYTHONPATH, I was able to get it working.

To add the directory permanently to the PYTHON PATH,  add this to your `~/.bashrc`

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/other/folder_containing_python_script`

Thanks to the post: [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)