# Moving an current DJango app to a different sub-directory

Tags: python, django

I have an app that was created in an "old" directory using "django-admin startproject businesscontacts"

**old location**:
C:\Users..\backendworkproj\businesscontacts

**moved to new location**: 
C:\Users..\backendworkproj\appmasterdata\businesscontacts

Now, of course, the app that was working is now broken. My understanding is that "C:\Users..\backendworkproj\appmasterdata" needs to be put in the PYTHONPATH.

I know that there are other explanations out there - but - I am trying to follow one of the responses listed here: [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

It says:
Instead of manipulating PYTHONPATH you can also create a path configuration file. First find out in which directory Python searches for this information:

To me, it is not clear exactly what is to go into the .pth file. I did not see anything stating whether or not a full-path is needed or a realtive-path or ...

In my case,

```
1. run python -m site --user-site
output => C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages

2. Made sure that the directory existed

3. echo "$HOME/foo/bar" > "$SITEDIR/somelib.pth"
```

Again, not sure what is supposed to be in the .pth file - or - what the name of the file should be (with Step #3)

TIA

## Update

Never mind. I tried to delete this message but was unable to do so. This is what I did:

In the 
`C:\Users\...Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages` directory, I created a file called  `appmaster.pth`

The contents of the .pth file are:
`C:\Users\...\backendworkproj\appmasterdata` (i.e. the full path to the project)

Things are working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

the    `django-admin startproject businesscontacts` makes a project, dose not make an app.

1.make a `new project` in the `new directory` by `django-admin startproject newdir/newbusinesscontacts`

2.add `apps` to your `project` by `python manage.py startapp app_name`

3.copy `old apps files` to your `new project apps`, you just created

4.add `app` to `installed_app` in the `project settings` file

5.`python manage.py makemigrations`

6.`python manage.py migrate`

7.`python manage.py runserver`

Comment: my mistake. I know that "python manage.py startapp "  is used to create apps (it was kinda late over here). I did not need info on how to create a project or app. What was needed was a way to ~move~ the app to a different sub-directory AFTER it has already been created

Comment: try to make a new project then make new app with django, then you can copy your code to it, instead of coping all project.