# Python: No module found even though it exists in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-import, diffbot

Consider I have the following project structure:

```
+PROJECT
|  +models
|  |  =__init__.py
|  |  =client.py
|  |  =config.py
|
|  +tests
|  | =__init__.py
|  | =example.py
|  | =example_two.py
|
|  README.md
|  requirements.txt
```

When I try to import a class from client and a variable from config into example.py, like so:

```
from models.config import var 
from models.client import Class
```

I receive a **ModuleNotFound Error** for both import statements. I know this question has been asked plenty of times before but those solutions don't resolve my issue. I tried placing client and config in the same level as the test folder. However, I received the same issue. It would be great If someone can help me work through this issue.

Comment: From which folder are you running it? And what's the command?

Comment: I'm running example.py from C:\user\documents\project\tests\

Comment: Your test scripts will have to modify sys.path to insert the PROJECT folder.

Comment: @Duncan I tried appending my project dir to the PATH but I still get the same error. I checked my path and the dir to the project folder is there. I really don't understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Create `PROJECT/__init__.py` as well as adding it to the path.

Answer (score 1):

Three possibilities come to my mind:

- The module just works for certain python versions (e.g. 3.5 but not 3.6).
- The path where your module is currently located does not appear in sys.path.
- The class you want to use must be specified while importing the module because it is not specified in the __init__.py of the module itself.

As far as I can tell, only the first option might cause your problem.
Nevertheless I would make a quick check with

```
import sys
sys.path
```

and in case that the correct path is really missing..

```
sys.path.append('PathToModule')
```

Comment: I appended my project dir to PATH but I still receive the same ModuleNotFound Error. It says in diffbot's repository that is was updated to work with python 3 here: https://github.com/diffbot/diffbot-python-client/pull/6. However I don't understand why his import sys statement to PATH resolves their issue and not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do a relative import ([PEP-328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-relative-imports)), but according to this [guide](https://chrisyeh96.github.io/2017/08/08/definitive-guide-python-imports.html#absolute-vs-relative-import), you can only go up until the level where you launched the script from, which is the `tests` directory in you case.

So you'll either have to add the `model` directory to the path, or add the source folder of your project to a .pth file in your site-packages as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12311321/1562285)

Comment: I receive error when trying the relative import E0402: Attempted relative import beyond top-level package.