# Custom modules import without typing folder name?

Tags: python, import, module

I have a folder called `Python Modules` which contains single-file modules I've made that I often use, for example one called `mytimer.py`. I added `Python Modules` to my Windows `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and I import it in other files with `import mytimer`.

But now I would like to put mytimer in a git repo, so I would need to put it in a folder (I don't want all my modules in a single repo) like `Python Modules\mytimer\mytimer.py`.

And I want to do this for many of the single-file modules in that folder.

Is there any way I can do this while still being able to import like `import mytimer` rather than `import mytimer.mytimer`, other than adding each folder individually to the `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the relevant python session aware of that directory, by adding that path to `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/repo/folder')
import a_module_in_that_folder
```

If you want to *permanently* add this path to `sys.path`, that's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Comment: That works, but I was hoping there would be some way I could set it up (maybe by doing something in `__init__.py` or PYTHONPATH) that wouldn't require me modifying all of the files that are already using `import mytimer`.

Comment: Updated to refer to a different post that should help

Comment: Thanks! That does solve my problem, I added a .pth file to my site-packages folder and wrote to it all the folder names in my `Python Modules` folder. This isn't as elegant a solution as I was hoping for but I think it's better than spamming my Windows PYTHONPATH