# Yet another Python Relative import mishap

Tags: python, python-3.x

#Background and Problem#
I'm trying to build a web-**scraper** to back up my social media accounts (summer project, I know it's useless).

I'm trying to create a nice class structure, so I've come up with the following structure (I accept critique, I'm pretty new to programming):

```
\social-media-backup

    \Files
        __init__.py
        File.py
        Image.py
        Video.py

    \SocialMedia
        SocialMediaFeed.py
        SocialMediaPost.py
        \Instagram
            __init__.py
            \MediaTypes
                __init__.py
                GraphImage.py
                GraphVideo.py
            \SearchTypes
                __init__.py
                InstagramUser.py
        \Twitter
        \VSCO
```

(Twitter and VSCO are, for now, empty. Anything without extension and starting with , is a folder. Every file has a class with the same name as the file inside)

#Questions#

1. Where can I learn Python's packaging system definitively? Any book or web-site recommendation?
2. How would I import Image into GraphImage? How would I import File into SocialMediaPost?
3. What do I need to write in `__init__.py` so as to `import SOME_PACKAGE` and have it import every module? (e.g.: import Files and have Files.Image and File.Video accessible).

(I know there are a lot of questions. They're written in order of importance)

#To accomplish importing File into SocialMediaPost I've tried:#

`from Files.File import File`

`from ...Files.File import File`

`import File`

`from File import File`

And almost any combination you can imagine.

I always get an `Unable to import`, `No module named '__main__.Files'` or `Attempted relative import beyond top-level package`.

#Expected behavior#

I'm used to Java's way of doing this, and I cannot figure out how to do this in Python. It seems so messed up. I really miss just adding a `package` and a folder tree from where the compiler would run.

**knocks desk** [THERE MUST BE A BETTER WAY](https://youtu.be/wf-BqAjZb8M?t=1383)

##THANKS!!##

Comment: Try starting from root of the project (but before, rename it to social_media_backup) - **"from social_media_backup.Files.File ..."**, also, it's widely recommended to name modules with lowercase, and use underscore instead of dash. Also, put **__init__.py** file in **social_media_backup**.

Comment: Putting `WhateverClass` in a file named `WhateverClass.py` is a *really bad* idea in Python. If you really want one class per file, at least name it `whateverclass.py` so you don't get super-confusing name collisions between the module and the class.

Comment: Stackoverflow is a better place for "One question at a time". One thing you should consider is, where do you launch this app from? You should search for `Minimal Python Package`. It's not very trivial, but you should take your time to read through Packaging

Comment: @Damian Thanks for your reply! I was using [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) to name my classes, but I mixed it up with how you do things in Java. I think something clicked in me with this: when you import a module you get access to the class within it as `module.class`. However, if you `from module import class`, you can just use `class`? I'll change my naming convention and try all other solutions after that.

Comment: @user2357112 I think I understand why with Damian's comment. I'll be sure to change that before attempting any other solution.

Comment: @user1767754 I'll read up on that. I know I have much reading to do, but I haven't found a clear and consice source that gives many examples. In my past (hobby) Python projects, I've always tried imports until it worked, but it's about time I learn this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of stuff is written about this... however most guides focus on how you do it, not what to do.

## For small to medium-sized projects

I have very good experience following these simple rules:

1. Do not mess with `sys.path`.
2. Have one "project root" directory with your modules / packages underneath (as you already do).
3. Use *absolute* imports always, except for "sister" modules.
4. Always run as module, i.e. using `python -m foo.bar`

Concrete example using your structure. Assuming that your entry point might be in `\SocialMedia\SocialMediaFeed.py`, use import statements:

- `from . import SocialMediaPost` (sister module)
- `from . import Instagram` (child module)
- `from Files import Image` (other module)

and run using: `python -m SocialMedia.SocialMediaFeed`

By running as module, you always have the project root (`social-media-backup`) added as "search path". This way absolute imports refering to its subfolders always work. By the way, you can print out the module search path using `import sys; print(sys.path)`.

Some of this might seem overcomplicated, but I found that following the above points pays out greatly as soon as you try to package up stuff for installation (keyword `setup.py`).

## When your project grows larger

Frequently, you have small "utility" modules that over time grow into libraries of their own right. E.g. there might be some module with helper functions for logging. The time comes when it makes sense to split them out into their own home (e.g. a separate git repository), for instance to reuse the utility in another project.

To do this:

1. Create the "library" project adhering to the workflow as above. Move your module(s) or package in question over into the new root folder.
2. Add `setup.py` or `setup.ini` to describe what exactly belongs to the library. There's lots of guides out there how to do it.
3. *Install* the library as "editable" installation: `pip install -e /path/to/library/project`

This will install kind-of-a "softlink" pointing to your development copy of the library source. The library module is now available in the python interpreter from any execution path just like the builtin ones. At the same time, if you edit files in the development folder, the changes are effective without installing it again.

Since in the main project, the module was only ever imported by absolute name as per rule #3, you don't need to change anything.

It is good practice to create a file `requirements.txt` where required modules for your project are listed. There you should add a line for the new library module. You can even teach pip to lookup such libraries in lokal paths, but that's a separate topic.

## 3rd question: how to "flatten" internal package structure for the user

Have `__init__.py` contain:

```
from . import File
from . import Image
from . import Video
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome reply. I was trying to avoid modifying `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` at all costs. 

When you say I should always use absolute imports, are they refered to my CMD execution directory? 

I mean, if I execute `python -m SocialMedia.SocialMediaFeed` standing in `PATH\TO\MY\PROJECT\DIRECTORY\social-media-downloader`, shouldn't I make all of my imports `from social-media-backup.some.other.folder import some_thing`? (I've already changed - for _ in my project, as suggested).

Comment: Yes - on script start, your current directory is added to the python search path (``sys.path`` variable). The import statement should not include the root folder name: ``from some.other.folder import some_thing``. Oh, and your package folder names must not include hyphens, dots, spaces or the like. Otherwise import is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I've fixed my naming after some commenters pointed it out.  After understanding that 1 class =/= 1 module, I've flattened my structure a la Python Zen. I was getting confused due to the `-m` flag needing to be executed from the main package directory, so I had import errors all over the place. But thanks to your answer, I now understand what Python does to `sys.path` and how that affects my imports. I'll refer back to it if at any time I find import troubles again! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would second the comments by Damian and user2357112 - try to avoid name collisions between folder, file and class/function when creating modules.

You probably won't be able to import anything outside of the current working directory without adding it to your PYTHONPATH. Adding a folder to your PYTHONPATH environment variable means that python will always check that folder when importing modules, so you'll be able to import it from anywhere.

There is a good thread on this already that will put you in the right direction:
[Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath) 
(It's a lot to cover in one post)

Comment: Thanks for replying! I kind of knew about `PYTHONPATH`, but was trying to leave it alone as that would become to "computer-specific". This, in turn, would make my application hard to port to another computer. Right? It seems a bit hacky to add entries to `PYTHONPATH` via script, so I'm trying to avoid it. Anyways, I still think it's a useful tool to have in the toolbox :).

Comment: Yes in your case PYTHONPATH is not the way to go, I failed to realise that portability is important in your case! I have added a single folder in my PYTHONPATH where all my custom modules can be imported from, but I should also have mentioned that you must be careful not to pollute the PYTHONPATH by overwriting existing modules! Torben's answer is much more useful for your problem!