# Use Sphinx doctest with :Example:

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest

Consider the following function:

```
# in mymodule.py:

def myfunc(num,mystring):
    """
    replicates a string

    :param num: a positive integer
    :param mystring: a string
    :return: string concatenated with itself num times

    :Example:
        >>> num = 3
        >>> mystring = "lol"
        >>> myfunc(num, mystring)
            "lollollol"
    """
    return num*mystring
```

How can I make Sphinx doctest work, in order to verify the example code in

`:Example:´ actually does work?
Whenever I run`make doctest`

it says that 3 tests were run, but 1 fails. Deleting the last two rows, starting with

`myfunc(num, mystring)`,

it says that 2 tests were run sucessfully. So I must be doing something wrong with that line. But what?

**EDIT** Here's the terminal output (traceback) for the full code; it seems that somehow it can't find the function for which I've written the docstring and I'm running the doctest:

```
Running Sphinx v1.8.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [doctest]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [] 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                                                 
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
running tests...

Document: index
---------------
**********************************************************************
File "index.rst", line ?, in default
Failed example:
    myfunc(num, mystring)
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/doctest.py", line 1330, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest default[2]>", line 1, in <module>
        myfunc(num, mystring)
    NameError: name 'myfunc' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in default
3 tests in 1 items.
2 passed and 1 failed.
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.

Doctest summary
===============
    3 tests
    1 failure in tests
    0 failures in setup code
    0 failures in cleanup code
build finished with problems.
Makefile:19: recipe for target 'doctest' failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sphinx+doctest is not importing the module. You can either help him in the docstring:

```
    :Example:
        >>> from mymodule import myfunc
        >>> myfunc(3, 'lol')
        'lollollol'
```

or add this in `conf.py`:

```
doctest_global_setup = '''
#if required, modif sys.path:
import sys
sys.path.append('../directory_containing_mymodule/')
from mymodule import *
'''
```

cf. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html

I'll be interested to hear if there are simpler answers.

Comment: This almost worked! The import in `:Example:` works, but if I add it to the `conf.py` it doesn't. Is there anything I could to get `conf.py` to work?

Comment: Is there actually any way that I could import everything in `conf.py` from the folder I'm working in, so that I dont' each time I create a new module and write docstrings for functions/methods inside it, I have to add those to `conf.py`?

Comment: Is your module already packaged (with `setup.py` and `__init__.py`)? sphinx may not be running in the folder that contains `mymodule.py`, so you probably need a `setup.py` or  set `PYTHONPATH` to be safe.

Comment: No, my module is just a file in `myproject`, whereas all Sphinx-related files are in `myproject/docs`. I've never packaged a module (and I don't know what to do with `PYTHONPATH` either), because I'm pretty new to Python; sorry :(

Comment: @l7ll7, PYTHONPATH (or sys.path) tells where your personal modules are (when they are not in current directory), see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath

Comment: I've added for example in conf.py a `sys.path` manipulation. You'll need to adapt to your files locations.

Answer (score 1):

On my terminal and outside Sphinx, I have to left align "lollollol" and use simple quotes in order to successfully run doctest:

```
    :Example:
        >>> num = 3
        >>> mystring = "lol"
        >>> myfunc(num, mystring)
        'lollollol'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either :(. I've attaced the traceback to my question.

Comment: Correct alignment and single quotes are indeed part of the solution. When executing `3 * "lol"` in an interactive session, the output is `'lollollol'`. Doctest does not accept `"lollollol"` as the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

As Demi-Lune has already said, one needs to add the filepath of your `.py` files to the `conf.py` file. But this should not be only passed to the command

```py
doctest_global_setup='''.... import sys'''
```

but rather add it to the general `conf.py` Path setup by declaring

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
```

substituting `'.'` by your absolute path. (You may also leave the `'.'` and add your `module.py` files to the source-folder of your sphinx project. Though I would not recommend this for larger projects.)

Then you only need to declare in the `conf.py` file

```py
doctest_global_setup='from module import *'
```

Now you may write in your `module.py` function

```py
def foo():
   """
   >>>foo()
   ['bar','fafa','bara']
   """
   return ['bar','fafa','bara']
```

The perk of declaring the path for the whole `conf.py` file is that other extensions such as autodoc can also detect your `module.py`. In this case you only need to write in your `.rst` file

```py
..autofunction:: module.foo()
```

It will take `foo()` from `module.py` and execute the doctest commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this kind of example will be correctly found and evaluated by [Sybil](https://sybil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with this in your `conftest.py`:

```
from sybil import Sybil
from sybil.parsers.doctest import DocTestParser

pytest_collect_file = Sybil(
    parsers=[DocTestParser()],
    patterns=['*.py'],
).pytest()
```