# Python 3 script is calling ROS files

Tags: python, ros

I am trying to install a ROS driver for a radar sensor.

The ROS publisher node is written in Python 3. It uses rosy to create messages and services.

When I call the script using `$ python3 filename.py`

I see the following output:

```
  File "umrr_can_publisher.py", line 3, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .client import spin, myargv, init_node, \
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 52, in <module>
    import roslib
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from roslib.launcher import load_manifest
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

I also tried to run my script in a virtual environment but with the same result.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rospkg` is a Python package that is usually provided by your ROS installation. If you are using a different interpreter than that used by the ROS installation, you will need to install this package manually, for example via `pip3 install rospkg`.

Alternatively, if your virtual environment's interpreter is compatible with the interpreter used by your ROS installation, you may also add the path to ROS' python packages to your [Python path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Comment: Although I am using Python 3 with ROS melodic just fine, `ros-melodic-desktop-full` does not install rospkg for Python 3. Installing via pip solved the problem. I think it should be available via the package manager, though.