# PIP 20.1 - WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.7.exe and pip3.exe

Tags: python, path

I was trying to upgrade Pip to version 20.1. The Download was successful then, I came across this error:

```
 WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.7.exe and pip3.exe  are installed in 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
```

Comment: A quick Google search for that error message returns a good amount of results, which aspect of this particular situation is not covered by the available resources? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC Thanks for the suggestion but, I've already tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is self-descriptive, you should copy pip.exe, pip3.7.exe and pip3.exe to Python Path

You may see how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)