# Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH in Windows?

Tags: python

Whenever I use sys.path.append, the new directory will be added. However, once I close python, the list will revert to the previous (default?) values. How do I permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH in Windows?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath, specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728643/5298150

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Comment: No it's not for windows users

Comment: Did you even check the links? How is this not for Windows? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728643/5298150