# Cannot install python 3 in visual studio code on my mac

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.10

I have been trying for several hours now but still I cannot download python 3.
I already have python extension installed and in the bottom right corner of my screen it even says python 3.10.0.
But when I go in the terminal and type "python" this is what it shows me:
Python 2.7.16 (default, Jan 26 2020, 23:50:38)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.31)] on darwin
And I cannot install Vpython because the terminal thinks I am still using
python 2!!!
Please help.

Comment: did you try `python3` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are calling the wrong version of python from your terminal. Try calling `python3` explicitly, see if that works? Some useful command line calls:

- `which python` \ `which python3` -> will show you the path to executable python program
- `python --version` \ `python3 --version` -> will show you the version of python
- `pip --version` -> will show you the version of pip

  - If not found, [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)

As an additional step, it's possible that the newer version of python hasn't been added to your profile.

- Here is a solution for that: [*Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61036803/16309709)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I now see python 3 in the terminal. But I still cannot run the command: "pip install vpython" here is what it says to me: "Python 3.10.0 (v3.10.0:b494f5935c, Oct  4 2021, 14:59:20) [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> pip install vpython
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install vpython
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?" Do you have any advices about that?

Comment: Try `pip3 install vpython`? @LéoLepage

Comment: Also, if my answer is helpful, please accept it? _(Also, considering asking a follow up Q if you find additional issues.)_ @LéoLepage

Comment: Sorry this command had the same result

Comment: Check if `pip` is installed? Run `which pip` or `which pip3` If not installed, install it.

Comment: where do I install it

Comment: Solved!!! Heres is a link to the solution I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5GL1obY_sI