# Python script requires "libpython3.8"

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi4, .so

I tried to run a python script I did not created that uses libraries I got with it (as .so files).
Every time I try to run it I get the same problem:
`ImportError: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`
The documentations file attached to the script claims that if I get this problem I need the libpython3.8 package.
I work on raspberry pi 4 with the newest OS (64-bit, Bookworm).

I tried to find ways to install "libpython3.8" but I couldn't understand what to do.
I ran it both on python 3.11 which is the one I had pre-installed, and also on python 3.8 which the documentation said was required. Both produced the same problem.
I also tried running the script on an older OS (32-bit, Bullseye).

I couldn't find any file named libpython3.8-something, as was suggested in other answers to other questions...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582092/importerror-libpython3-8-so-1-0-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-o)

Comment: Did you try https://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages/55-raspbian-python#l?

Comment: You should update to Bookworm. It is including Python 3.11