# Pandas Installed For All Python Versions But Module Can't Be Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to modify an AI for a game on the steam store. The AI communicates through the game with the use of a mod called the communication mod. The AI is made using a python project. The package I am trying to modify is https://github.com/ForgottenArbiter/spirecomm and the mod is https://github.com/ForgottenArbiter/CommunicationMod.
I want to add the pandas package and the job lib package as imports so I can use a model I have made for the AI. When I try to run the game + mod after adding the pandas and joblib packages as imports I get this error in the error log.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ross/downloads/spirecomm-master/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from spirecomm.ai.agent import SimpleAgent
  File "/Users/ross/Downloads/spirecomm-master/spirecomm/ai/agent.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

This issue only happens when the game is running and the mod tries to run. if I just run the file in terminal it is able to compile/run and send the ready signal

I have checked that I have these modules installed and it is installed. I am on an M1 Mac and I have several different versions of python installed but I have checked them all and it is installed for each of them. I have also opened the python package using pycharm and added pandas and joblib to the python interpreter as a package.
Another thing I have tried is modifying the setup.py file to say that pandas and joblib are required. I then ran it again but I am not sure if this had any effect because I have already run it before.

Answer (score 0):

There is limited help that can be provided without knowing the framework that you are is using but hopefully this will give you some starting points to help.

If you are getting a "No module named 'pandas'" error, it is because you have imported pandas in your code but your python interpreter cannot find it. There are two major reasons this will happen, either it is not installed (which you say has definitely happened) or it is not in the location the interpreter expects (most likely).

The first thing you can do is make sure the pandas install is in the PYTHONPATH. To do this look at [Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath).

Secondly, you say you have several versions of python and have installed the module for all versions but you most likely have several instances of at least one version. Many IDEs, such as PyCharm, create a virtual environment when you create a new project and place in it a new instance of python interpreter, or more accurately a link to one version of python. Within this virtual environment, the IDE then loads the modules it has been told to load and thus makes them available for import to the code using that particular environment.
In your case I suspect you may be using a virtual environment that has not had pandas loaded into it. You need to investigate your IDEs documentation if you do not know how to load it. Alternatively you can instruct the IDE to use a different virtual environment (one that does have pandas loaded) - again search documentation for how to do this.

Finally, if all else fails, you can specifically tell your code where to look for the module using the sys.path.append command in your code.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/your/pandas/module/path')
import pandas
```