# How to import from absolute path in python 3.8?

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

I am trying to import a module given an absolute path. I have read through some posts and I chose to follow one method mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311583/19947267 but for some reason it doesnt work; below is my directory.
my example directory looks like this:

```
<root>
 |
 +- /std1
 |   |
 |   +- main.py
 |
 +- /std2
 |   |
 |   +- lib.py
```

I cd to `/std1` and now I want to import a module from `lib.py`, but when I implement the following code:

```
import sys 
import os
configfile = '~/std2/'
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser(configfile)))
from std2.lib import target_module
```

It cant seem to recognise std2.lib, the error message was

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'std2.lib'`

is there something I did wrong here? Can anyone please help?

Comment: 1. You said "<root>" but use `~` (user directory) - which is it? 2. If it's always one directory back from std1, you could play with pathlib and `__file__` to just get current file's path, then parent (std1), then its parent (<root>) and append that to PATH.

Comment: this is almost never the right way to do things. Anyway, did you try adding an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Messing with `sys.path` is almost never the right way to do this. If you *must* though, then you need to understand that if you append `~/std2/` to the search path, it won't be able to find the name `std2`, because the import system searches *inside of `std2`*. And that is what your code does, your approach wasn't working because of this behavior of `os.path.dirname` when the string has a leading forward slash:

```
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser('~/std2/'))
'/Users/juan/std2'
>>> os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser('~/std2'))
'/Users/juan'
```

So, the simplest fix is:

```
import sys 
import os
configfile = '~/std2' # NOTE NO TRAILING FORWARD SLASH
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser(configfile)))
import std2.lib
```

Or instead, you can change your import statement to use just `lib`, so:

```
import sys 
import os
configfile = '~/std2/'
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.expanduser(configfile)))
import lib
```

Better yet, you should use `pathlib` instead of `os.path`:

```
import sys
import pathlib
configfile = pathlib.Path("~/std2/")
sys.path.append(str(configfile.expanduser()))
import lib
```

But if you wanted to be able to import `std2`, you could add the parent directory to the path:

```
import sys
import pathlib
configfile = pathlib.Path("~/std2/")
sys.path.append(str(configfile.expanduser().parent))
import std2.lib
```

(See how much nicer `pathlib` is?)

But I really must reiterate, you almost certainly shouldn't be messing with `sys.path` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an empty file called **init**.py in std2 and append the root directory to the Pythonpath ([explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath))